# Backbone.js I want to do model.fetch and have the data reflected back in the source collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm really looking to understand the concept here (as opposed to receiving a code solution).

I have a collection that was populated by a fetch.  I want to take a single model from the collection, fetch the latest data from the server, then have the data that came from the server put back into the collection's version of the model.

Restating with terms from Backbones docs: I'd like to ensure that I have the latest server state.  I won't care about "change" events that are triggered because I'm expecting the model to change almost every time.  Fetch *resets the model's state from the server*, so I should just be able to do something like this, right?:

[pseudo]

```
model.fetch();
```

in the fetch success handler call one of these:

```
this: collection.add(model, {merge: true});
..or: collection.set(model);
```

If that's not enough to accomplish my task, what concept am I missing?

**EDIT - adding details**

I call fetch():

```
controller.model.fetch({
    success: function(model){
        console.log(model);
        updateView();
    },
    error: function(){
        console.error('error fetching contact model');
    }
});
```

The success callback is fired after the fetch().  I can see that the model has new data and that the Image has been modified and needs to be re-downloaded:

[image: ImageDateLastUpdated has changed]

When I call my function that updates the view, nothing changes visibly because the latest data is still in the "changed" member...it seems.  What's the standard way to get the latest data from "changed" into the "attributes" member?  And is this made clear in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "collection's version of the model"

If you refer to a model in the collection and call fetch, there's nothing else needs to be done.
This model is already a part of the collection and the new data will populate.

Objects in javascript are passed by reference, so unless you clone it seeing something like `model.clone()`, you are referring to the same object.

Comment: There must be something else.  My code reaches the fetch's success handler.  The model's "attributes" property hasn't changed, but now the "changed" member has a new 0th child with the new values I'm expecting.  Based on the doc's "[fetch] resets the model's state from the server", I'm expecting the values I see in changed[0] to be what "resets the model's state" and be in the "attributes" member.  Apparently I'm misunderstanding or missing something in the docs??

Comment: not sure what you mean by `changed[0]`. Either the attributes changed, or they hasn't. can you explain what an "0th child" is? IS the data not updating, or us the "change" event not firing?

Comment: In Chrome dev tools when I console.log() the model after the fetch, the model has an attributes member and a changed member (and others).  The changed member has a child object "0" that consists of the same named values that I see in attributes but it has the latest values obtained from the server.  How do I get the latest values that are found in changed to the correct place in the model  so that my bound view will display the new values?

Comment: Also, I haven't subscribed to the change event.  Is this a requirement to use the model.fetch() method?  And if it's required, do I also need to run any code in the change event for the values to get updated in the model?

Comment: your screenshot refers to different attributes, the top one is in the top level, the lower one is inside the `0` object;

Comment: All I know is that the lower one has the values I want, but the lower one is not the one represents my model's state.  Thus, the docs' "Resets the model's state from the server" doesn't seem quite accurate.

Comment: I discovered the issue.  I hadn't noticed that there was also an attributes[0] in my output.  On the server side I was using the same code for the model.fetch as I was for the collection.fetch.  I just had to return the zeroeth item from the server when called from the model.fetch and it started working.  Sorry and thank you for your help, Uzi.